# Sum of the even number of fibonacci series starting with 1,2,3... in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, fibonacci

Below code is written in javascript and it is working fine for a certain limit of range.I want to check it out for range of 2 million and it is showing result as  infinity? **How to handle sum of large numbers in javascript?**

```
function fibanocci(n){
    var first = 1;
    var second = 2;
    var next = 0;
    var sum = 2;
    for(var i=0;i<n-2;i++){
        next = first+second;
        first = second;
        second = next;
        if(next%2==0){
            sum = sum+next;
        }
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Comment: You obviously can't store this large numbers in a JavaScript Number, you need a big integer implementation

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence is exponential. Are you sure you want the sum of the first 2 million numbers (a number of the order of half a million digits), or just the sum of all numbers below 2 million?

Comment: if you realy need big big big numbers try something like http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/

Comment: Project Euler problem 2 asks for the sum of the even Fibonacci numbers less than 4 million, and it also uses the same unusual starting values of 1 and 2 instead of saying that fibonacci(0)=0, fibonacci(1)=1, fibonacci(2)=1. See https://projecteuler.net/problem=2. I suspect that Phylogenesis is right and this is what was intended instead.

Answer (score 0):

With a number that big you're probably hitting the max number size. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) says that the largest number javascript can deal with is `9007199254740992`. I suppose anything above that might result in infinity.

Comment: That's the largest integer that can be held. Above that, it switches to a 64-bit double representation that can store up to about 1e308 with 15 digits of precision.

Comment: I doesn't actually switch, it is always a IEEE754 double according to the ECMAScript specification. This is just a turning point, where the integers are no longer safely representable.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to work with such huge numbers, you should consider using a BigInteger implementation for JavaScript, like [this one](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum), as the biggest safely representable integer in a JavaScript `Number` is `2^53-1 = 9007199254740992`.